# Python - Replace only exact word in string

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace only specific word in one string. However, some other words have that word inside but I don't want them to be changed.

For example, for the below string I only want to replace `x` with `y` in `z` string. how to do that?

```
x = "the"
y = "a"
z = "This is the thermometer"
```

Comment: I suggest using `.split()` to convert your string into a list of words, then replacing the word that equals your keyword, then rebuilding the string from the list.

Comment: what if I have string with 10k words. then it wouldn't be efficient :/

Comment: @MichaelO.this will not work in general case - test for `x = 'is'`

Comment: Alternative is to use regular expressions, which is not very efficient either. You should test for yourself which method suits you more.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\bthe\b', 'a', z)`

Comment: @Austin more like `z = re.sub(r'\b' + x + r'\b', y, z)`

Comment: thanks for the help.

what if a word was like this.

"this is 114-221 #114-221"

and i only want to replace first 114-221 but not second one?
@Błotosmętek

Comment: For the solution using split: it will work without change; for Austin's solution you need to add `count=1` to re.sub parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern=r'\bthe\b' # \b - start and end of the  word
repl='a'
string = 'This is the thermometer'

string=re.sub(pattern, repl, string)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. what if a word was like this. "this is 114-221 #114-221" and i only want to replace first 114-221 but not second one?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use `re.sub(x, y, z)`.
You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) for more information.